# Setting default state dynamically + onMouseEnter

Tags: reactjs

I have created a scoreboard that updates when a user hovers over each team's card, hovering over a team's card also changes some CSS attributes to make it stand out.
The current default state value is "0", I need the default value to be equal to the top team's score.
Below is the TeamCard component that updates TopGroups with onMouseEnter:

```
const TeamCard = ({
  data,
  setDisplayGoals,
  setDisplayMilestones,
  setDisplayPoints,
}) => {
  return (
    <TeamCardStyle>
      <Row className="d-flex justify-content-between">
        {!data && <Spinner />}
        {data &&
          data.getGroupScores &&
          data.getGroupScores.slice(0, 4).map((group, index) => {
            return (
              <Col
                key={guid()}
                className="teamCard mt-2 mb-2 mx-1"             
                onMouseEnter={() => [
                  setDisplayGoals(group.goalsDone),
                  setDisplayPoints(group.totalScore),
                  setDisplayMilestones(group.milestonesDone),
                ]}
              >
                <Row>
                  {/* <div className="arrow-down" /> */}
                  <p key={guid}>{seed[index]}</p>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <Col className="hideSmall">
                    <img className="mouseOn" src="../images/group.png" />
                    <img
                      className="mouseOff"
                      src="../images/groupSelected.png"
                    />
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <p key={guid}>{group.name.slice(0, 14)}</p>
              </Col>
            );
          })}
      </Row>
    </TeamCardStyle>
  );
};
```

This is a snippet of the TopGroups component:
[image]

```
const TopGroups = () => {
  const currentQTR = `Q${moment().quarter()} ${moment().year()}`;
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_GROUP_SCORES, {
    variables: { quarter: currentQTR },
  });
  if (data) {
    const sortedGroups = data.getGroupScores.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.totalScore > b.totalScore) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a.totalScore < b.totalScore) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    const test = data.GoalsDone;
  }
  if (error) {
    return <p>An error has occured</p>;
  }
  if (loading) {
    <Spinner />;
  }

  const [displayGoals, setDisplayGoals] = useState("0");
  const [displayPoints, setDisplayPoints] = useState("0");
  const [displayMilestones, setDisplayMilestones] = useState("0");

  return (
    <div className="row-12">
      <TeamCard
        data={data}
        setDisplayGoals={setDisplayGoals}
        setDisplayPoints={setDisplayPoints}
        setDisplayMilestones={setDisplayMilestones}
      />
```

I have included a picture of the app when it first loads, I would like those zeros to be the #1 Team's score, in this case it should represent Team Clown Car.

Comment: Since you are already sorting the data by group scores couldn't you just change the useState to something like .useState(sortedGroups[0]);

Comment: I tried that but it caused an error, sortedGroups is not defined.

Comment: in that case you could do useState((loading)?"0":sortedGroups[0]); to ensure that it will only update it once the data is loaded

Comment: I got the same undefined error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use something like this when you get the data

```
useEffect(()=>{
setDisplayGoals("first group's goals"),
setDisplayPoints("first group's points"),
setDisplayMilestones("first group's Milestones")
},[])
```

you get the idea. Empty brackets will cause useEffect only run on the first render.